# WADL File for PayPal's REST API

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

is there any WADL-File for PayPal's REST API? I try to create a proof of concept for E-Payments at my company and would like to implement some API-Calls in our backend and need a WADL-File.

Best regards.

Comment: Hmm .... no mention of WADL anywhere on PP documentation. Are you sure you don't mean [WSDL](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture/#)

Comment: Hey Jamie, yeah its WADL. It is especially for REST-APIs. WSDL only supports SOAP-APIs